# My gameObject does not rotate while jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My `gameObject` does not rotate while jumping. I used `GetComponent().rotation = Quaternion.identity;` for rotation but the `gameObject` still does not rotate. What is the problem? And how do I adjust the speed of the rotation? Here's my jump script:

Comment: in which method you are putting this code?

Comment: @NasirKhan void Update()

Comment: `GetComponent().rotation` ?? how did this even compile?

Comment: I want to rotate the cube while it is jumping, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quaternion.identity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html) means no rotation {0,0,0,0}, whenever this code block is called the gameObject's rotation will become the standard rotation value.

If this was intentional and the rotation of the gameObject is not {0,0,0,0} then perhaps you are modifying the rotation elsewhere?

Comment: I want to rotate the cube while it is jumping, how do I do it?

Comment: You could try using [Transform.Rotate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) on the gameObject to rotate it by a value of you choosing. E.G. transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,10,0) * Time.DeltaTime);

Answer (score 1):

```
GetComponent().rotation = Quaternion.identity;
```

Couple issues with this line.  First off, just use transform.rotation... no need to call GetComponent() here.  Also, `Quaternion.identity` is just the 'zero' rotation.  What kind of rotation are you actually trying to apply here because you shouldn't see anything using identity.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html

To apply real rotation use something like (where "speed" is a float var where you can set how fast you want your cube to rotate):

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: I want to rotate the cube while it is jumping, how do I do it?